# SQL Show most current record for each task by date

Tags: html, mysql, date, sqldatasource, sqlcommand

I want to show the most recently updated record for each task.
Currently I am only getting the most recent of all records no matter what task.

Here is the front end code

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="GrabAssignedTasks" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:DefaultConnection %>" 
            SelectCommand="SELECT Backlog.Story, Tasks.Task, Tasks.EstimatedHours, Tasks.UserStoryTaskID, Tasks_Log.TaskLogID, Tasks_Log.HoursLeft, Tasks_Log.ModifiedDate 
             FROM Backlog 
             INNER JOIN Tasks ON Backlog.UserStoryID = Tasks.UserStoryID 
             INNER JOIN Tasks_Log ON Tasks.UserStoryTaskID = Tasks_Log.TaskID 
             WHERE (Tasks.OwnershipID = @UserID) AND (Tasks_Log.ModifiedDate = (SELECT MAX(ModifiedDate) AS Expr1 
            FROM Tasks_Log AS Tasks_Log_1))">
            <SelectParameters>
                <asp:SessionParameter Name="UserID" SessionField="loggedInUser" />
            </SelectParameters>
        </asp:SqlDataSource>



    </div>
       <header class="jumbotron hero-spacer">

         <asp:Button ID="BackToTasks" runat="server" Text="Back" OnClick="BackToTasks_Click" CssClass="btn btn-primary btn-large" />


        <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataSourceID="GrabAssignedTasks" Height="179px" Width="829px" OnSelectedIndexChanged="HoursChange_SelectedIndexChanged">
            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Story" HeaderText="Story" SortExpression="Story" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Task" HeaderText="Task" SortExpression="Task" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="EstimatedHours" HeaderText="Estimated Hours" SortExpression="EstimatedHours" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="UserStoryTaskID" HeaderText="UserStoryTaskID" SortExpression="UserStoryTaskID" InsertVisible="False" ReadOnly="True" HeaderStyle-CssClass="hidden-field" ItemStyle-CssClass="hidden-field"/>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="TaskLogID" HeaderText="TaskLogID" SortExpression="TaskLogID" InsertVisible="False" ReadOnly="True" HeaderStyle-CssClass="hidden-field" ItemStyle-CssClass="hidden-field"/>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="HoursLeft" HeaderText="Hours Left" SortExpression="HoursLeft" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="ModifiedDate" HeaderText="Last Updated" SortExpression="ModifiedDate" />
                <asp:CommandField ShowSelectButton="True" />
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
        </header>
```

I have nothing specific to this in the C# code.

Here is a picture of the table in the database I am using.
[Database table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6T6O7.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not joining Table Tasks_Log with Tasks_Log_1, so what happens is that only entries in Tasks_Log where the modified date matches "30/11/2015" get returned, regardless of the task.  Add an entry in that WHERE clause for Tasks_Log_1 to ensure you are also matching on the correct TaskID:

```
SELECT Backlog.Story, Tasks.Task, Tasks.EstimatedHours, Tasks.UserStoryTaskID, Tasks_Log.TaskLogID, Tasks_Log.HoursLeft, Tasks_Log.ModifiedDate 
    FROM Backlog 
    INNER JOIN Tasks ON Backlog.UserStoryID = Tasks.UserStoryID 
    INNER JOIN Tasks_Log ON Tasks.UserStoryTaskID = Tasks_Log.TaskID 
    WHERE (Tasks.OwnershipID = @UserID)
    AND (Tasks_Log.ModifiedDate = 
        (SELECT MAX(ModifiedDate) 
         FROM Tasks_Log AS Tasks_Log_1
         WHERE Tasks_Log_1.TaskID = Tasks_Log.TaskID))
```

Comment: Russ you are a beautiful man, works like a charm :) thank you so much